# Google Sheets API enabled other services and APIs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google

I got an email stating my services are suspended for doing cryptocurrency mining, which is not true.

I have enabled Google Sheets API project in a project I created.

I noticed it also enabled a Google Compute API and Google Service Account API. Is this normal? Or have those been compromised in some way?

Comment: Your Google account is compromised. [Take action now to recover it.](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6294825) After completing recovery you will also need to revoke all of the API keys and generate new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to the email stating that your services are suspended for doing cryptocurrency mining, you will have to respond to that email and communicate with the team in charge of that department.

On my end, I tested the Google Sheets API turned on, while the Google Compute API and Google Service Account API were turned off. The latter did not turn itself on.

If you would like to monitor when your API had turned on, you should look into the following [viewing logs](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/audit-logging#viewing_logs) section

Comment: Yes I contacted them. They cleared it up and had to regenerate a Service Account Key. But problem solved. Thanks :)